# We left him behind

Tags: word-usage

Four friends are running.(for fun.) So one of them asks:
Where's C?

So others reply:

> We left him behind. But he'll soon catch up with us.

Is the use of 'leave behind" natural? B couldn't keep up with the speed of others.

Comment: Yeah. Please look up *leave behind* in a couple of dictionaries.

Answer (score 1):

Here behind acts as an adverb meaning **at or towards the back of sb/sth** and it modifies the verb **leave**.